# Buffer/expand point contained inside another polygon

Tags: qgis, sql, buffer

I have a point at one corner of a square. I want to buffer that point with a specified size, but I don't want the buffer to extend beyond the boundary of the polygon behind it. The buffer should conform to the frame without losing its 'area. It´s best if the buffer is square.

The pink in the picture is the buffer I want.
I assume I have to make a SQL query of some sort, but I do not know how to do it.

[image: This shows what I mean]

The polygons are not all rectangles, some are more like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the buffer should be circular?

Comment: Preferebly square.

Comment: Remember to update the question - comments are transient and are deleted once no longer needed. A couple more questions (2) Should the point be at the centre of the buffer? (3) Should the buffer touch two sides of the polygon? (Note you can't necessarily have (2) and (3))

Comment: "*I assume I have to make a sql querry of some sort, [...]*" - well, if you are working with *MS Paint* then no. Please add tags for the (one) language/framework/software of your choice. If the frame is *strictly* rectangular, find its quadrant the point sits in, then the cell of a grid originated at the respective corner of the frame and having the cell size of your desired diameter. Both can be done cheaply via coordinate rounding. If the frame is not axis aligned, a rotation of all coordinates can be applied and reversed.

Comment: the picture is for demonstration purposes only (to simplify). I use qgis of course

Comment: I like that picture. Didn't see the QGIS tag, sorry.

Comment: no worries mate

Comment: Also, does the polygon have any identifying feature (ie a unique name, id etc)?

Comment: So... you have a polygon, providing the boundary which the buffer should not exceed. You have a point, which should be inside a circular buffer, which in turn is of a specific size/area. Is this summed up correctly?

Comment: That is correct :)

Comment: @TomBrennan, in this simplified case the point do not have a unique value.

Comment: But what about the polygon? Does it have an identifying feature? And as mentioned before, remember to update the question with any clarifications, not just the comments. For example, you've said a circular buffer to @Erik, but a square buffer to me...

Comment: @TomBrennan copy that. It does not have an special feature. Imagine you´ll make a square polygon. Put a point in the corner, and then buffer the point. I don´t see the purpose of giving them special features.

Comment: If you get your distance from the point to the polygon edge then use that to calculate a square buffer, will that do what you need?  To get that distance see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/427508/calculate-distance-in-miles-from-point-to-polygon-edge-in-qgis

Comment: That would probably work. But I need this to be automated. In my project i have hundreds of these points and rectangles.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the *Geometry by Expression* tool on the point layer with this expression:

```sql
-- create a square buffer (change size as necessary)
with_variable('buf', bounds(buffer($geometry, 500)),
-- get the polygon that the current point is within (change 'polygons' for the name of your layer)
with_variable('poly', overlay_within('polygons', @geometry, limit:=1)[0],

    case 
        -- left and bottom edge outside 
        when x_min(@buf) < x_min(@poly) and y_min(@buf) < y_min(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, abs(x_min(@buf) - x_min(@poly)), abs(y_min(@buf) - y_min(@poly)))
        
        -- right and bottom edge outside
        when x_max(@buf) > x_max(@poly) and y_min(@buf) < y_min(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, -abs(x_max(@buf) - x_max(@poly)), abs(y_min(@buf) - y_min(@poly)))
        
        -- left and top edge outside
        when x_min(@buf) < x_min(@poly) and y_max(@buf) > y_max(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, abs(x_min(@buf) - x_min(@poly)), -abs(y_max(@buf) - y_max(@poly)))
        
        -- right and top edge outside
        when x_max(@buf) > x_max(@poly) and y_max(@buf) > y_max(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, -abs(x_max(@buf) - x_max(@poly)), -abs(y_max(@buf) - y_max(@poly)))
        
        -- bottom edge outside
        when y_min(@buf) < y_min(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, 0, abs(y_min(@buf) - y_min(@poly)))
        
        -- top edge outside
        when y_max(@buf) > y_max(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, 0, -abs(y_max(@buf) - y_max(@poly)))
        
        -- left edge outside
        when x_min(@buf) < x_min(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, abs(x_min(@buf) - x_min(@poly)), 0)
        
        -- right edge outside
        when x_max(@buf) > x_max(@poly)
        then translate(@buf, -abs(x_max(@buf) - x_max(@poly)), 0)

        -- no edges outside
        else @buf
    end
))
```

Ensure that the `Output geometry type` is `Polygon`.

[image]

##### Result

The blue lines represent the original square buffer. The red is that buffer shifted if its geometry exceeds the polygon boundary.

[image]

Comment: You are getting really close. This is almost perfect. But what if all these rectangles are not "perfect" rectangles? What if all the polygons are a bit different. Some are triangles (not perfect triangles). The background polygon is more like a map polygon with all kinds of twists and turns. I have updated the question with the types of polygons.

Comment: There was no mention of irregular polygons before. I will take another look when I have time.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: It is always important to make the question as clear as possible from the very beginning. Otherwise, people might invest a lot of time for finding a solution. It can then be quite frustrating to hear that this solution is not really what you want, but add further conditions. In such I case, I would consider this further condition to be another question that you can post separately, with a link to the initial question. You can then accept the answer by @Matt

Comment: I thought that that sql query would fit all kinds of polygons. I Think @Matt has done a magnificent job here. I`m sorry for my lack of knowlege on how to operate in this forum. I hope I can be forgiven.

Comment: The square buffer should be oriented to the main angle of the feature, or it should be as I have created them above?

Comment: As you have done it is correct. It would be nice if you could run this buffer on all kinds of polygons. Not only rectangles.

Comment: Just let me know, @matt, if you don´t have time